# How to create an array out of all ascii charactors in php?

Tags: php

I am having an issue inserting \ and " into an array. How do I resolve the issue?

```
array(" ","!",""","#","$","%","&","'","(",")","*","+",",","-",".","/","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",":",";","<","=",">","?","@","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","[","\","]","^","_","`","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","{","|","}","~",");
```

?>

Comment: Escape them with a  "\" in front. E.g.: `"\""`

Comment: Why bother crafting this very list manually? That's just all ASCII printables. Easier with `array_map("chr", range(32, 126))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. You need to escape two values over here **"""** to **"\""** and **"\"** into `"\\"` and you have extra **,"** at the end of the array

```
array(" ","!","\"","#","$","%","&","'","(",")","*","+",",","-",".","/","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",":",";","<","=",">","?","@","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","[","\\","]","^","_","`","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","{","|","}","~");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the characer

Tried:

```
array("\\","\"");
```